# I am working on a project and I want to run another python file only when asked to but I cant figure out the code

Tags: python, import

I am working on a project and I want to run another python file only when asked to but I cant figure out the code

```
import rock_paper_scissor as rps

if 'rock paper scissor' in command:
rps.play()
```

Comment: you need an `input` statement

Comment: How user to be asked  input through terminal ? voice? in both of the cases writing a script to enter input is base script...Consider starting from here https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp

Comment: voice..........

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the input when calling the script like this:

```
yourscript.py rock
```

You can use the `sys` libary to get arguments:

```
import sys
if sys.argv[1] == "rock" or "paper" or "scissors":
    rps.play()
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: i want my main code to run first but this code is running first

Comment: maybe because u didnt intend it? like this:

https://gist.github.com/vince-vibin/010dda524cc9b4e0e9d2c252a9e41929